# Combine jQuery scripts

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying to combine the two jquery script... Basic bootstrap carousel with jquery mobile touch swipe feature. all my attempts have resulted in errors or not working at all

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
interval: 5000
})

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
});

});

</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {  
         $("#myCarousel").swiperight(function() {  
              $(this).carousel('prev');  
                });  
           $("#myCarousel").swipeleft(function() {  
              $(this).carousel('next');  
       });  
    });  
</script>
```

**combine attempt**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000
})

        $("#myCarousel").swiperight(function() {  
              $(this).carousel('prev');  
                });  
        $("#myCarousel").swipeleft(function() {  
              $(this).carousel('next');  
       });


$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: For someone with enough experience on this site you could certainly expand the question with some more detail.   What isn't working?  What errors are you getting? Perhaps make a jsfiddle.net and demonstrate what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Well, i can't fix your problem because we have to little information. But one thing i can say, it's not wise to rely on the order of execution when using multiple $(document).ready() statements. In this case the carousel function has to be finished before the swipe function can work. In your case with multiple document ready's you can never know for sure.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker sorry about that, I did not have everything highlight when copy and pasting. I've added the combine part.

Comment: Have you checked the docs for the bootstrap carousel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have formatted the code for you neatly. This should work unless you have other errors that you're not revealing to us.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    })

    $("#myCarousel").swiperight(function() {  
        $(this).carousel('prev');  
    });  
    $("#myCarousel").swipeleft(function() {  
        $(this).carousel('next');  
    });

    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
        // you haven't defined any actions here
    });
});
</script>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel are the docs.